# Angular x-editable + sorting and pagination

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angular-xeditable to add update and delete grid data.However I also need the angular pagination and sorting functionalities.Any idea on how can combine these both??

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css for Pagination:

```
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
```

Include pagination in your html after Add button as follows:

```
<pagination class="nomargin pull-right"
      total-items="totalItems"
      items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
      ng-model="currentPage"
      ng-change="pageChanged()">
</pagination>
```

You would need to do some work on your Controller with regards to the scope in the pagination tag above.

Visit the following:

http://plnkr.co/edit/APCMh0?p=preview

http://codepen.io/roktas/pen/AFEsh